# NTRIPClient update nmea

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote an ntrip client in C using sockets(http://read.pudn.com/downloads116/sourcecode/unix_linux/493018/NtripLinuxClient.c__.htm), Receiving the reqest works fine, but after some time the server stops sending correction data because I do not now how to send nmea updates to the server.

Does anyone know how that would work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to send your_nmea + '\r\n' regularly and that should work.